# Why this part doesnt go smoothly even when I use smooth vertices?

Tags: modeling, shaders, vertices

I want my model to go smoothly in the section below, I've already used flat shading or smooth shading, and use vertex smoothing so it won't hurt so much the sight of the model. It's disturbing, please a little bit of help.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: have you set autosmooth?

Comment: I've applied in the normals section auto smoothing, and nothing happens. But thanks, it was unchecked.

Comment: it's probably because you have a topology that flattens the shape, i.e. edge loops along the angles that sharpen these edges, shading > smooth or subdividing won't fix anything, please show the wireframe

Comment: can you show us your wireframe? I quess you have beveled edges or something so that it makes it looks like this

Comment: Try using Loop Tools > Circle on one or more of the latitudes,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere along the line, there has been a linear subdivision of the polygonal sides of your profile. See if you can get away with (the shipped add-on) *Loop Tools > Circle* with 'Best Fit' on selected latitudes:

[image]

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd> select an edge-ring
- Header > Select > Edge Loops
- Loop tools > Circle

Comment: Thank you so much, indeed was the topology